# Why is the last argument of _mm_permute_ps an int?

Tags: c, intel, api-design, intrinsics, avx

GCC kindly informed me that the last argument of the SIMD intrinsic `_mm_permute_ps` must be an 8-bit immediate. Why then is its last argument declared as expecting an `int`?

```
__m128     _mm_permute_ps(__m128  a, int imm8);
__m256d _mm256_permute_pd(__m256d a, int imm8);
```

Would an 8-bit type parameter not provide a more helpful interface to the end user?

Comment: Blame Intel. They come up with the intrinsics.

Comment: If it has to be an immediate value, does it really make any difference?

Comment: There is a school of thought that says "every integer should be of type `int`, unless there is a darn good reason for it to be some other type". Based on my experience spanning three decades, I would tend to agree with this design philosophy. As @immibis points out, there doesn't seem to be a "darn good reason" here.

Comment: And, according to the documentation it's actually only 4 bits (for both functions).

Comment: @immibis: the hardware ignores bits `[7:4]`, but the machine encoding uses a whole byte for the `imm8`.  You can certainly put whatever you want there.  (Not that it matters; you're not writing in asm so there's no guarantee the compiler-generated asm will even contain a `vpermilps`, let alone use your immediate unchanged.  e.g. clang's shuffle optimizer probably forgets about the ignored bits.)

Answer (score 1):

It is consistent with all the other intrinsics taking a shuffle vector or immediate argument. Probably to indicate it is an integer and not a character, while avoiding depending on stdint.h for int8_t.

The funnier part from a C++ point of view is that isn't constexpr, so you can give it non-compile time arguments, which then causes fun stuff for the compiler. I once tried improving the intrinsics for gcc in a way that assumed the immediate argument was compile-time, and it broke a surprisingly amount of code.

Comment: Some compilers will reject it if it isn't a compile-time constant. IMO, that's the correct behavior since such intrinsics are supposed to map closely to the instruction that it represents rather than abstract interface that needs to be implemented by any means necessary.

Comment: GCC does still require intrinsic args that correspond to an immediate to be a compile-time constant *after inlining*.  So for non-optimized code, the definition of `_mm_shuffle_epi32` in terms of `__builtin_ia32_pshufd` is a macro, while the `#ifdef __OPTIMIZE__` version is an inline function declared with `__attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))`. But even that's not sufficient for it to work at `-O0`, because that level of non-optimization means that constant-propagation doesn't work even after force-inlining.